# Textbox autofill not in correct position in safari

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, safari, autofill

Has anyone experience this weird issue on safari?
Textbox autofill is not at its correct position, please see screenshot below.
I have been searching for answers in google for almost a day, still no luck.

**This is the built-in autofill feature of safari.**

Here is the markup:

index.php

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="nav"></div>
     <div id="content">
          <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src="add_user.php" frameborder="0"></iframe>
     </div>
     ....
  </body>
</html>
```

add_user.php

```
<html>
    ....
   <body>
     <form method="post">
          <h3>Add User (Admin only)
          <div id="msg">Please enter First and Last Name.</div>
          <ul>
              <li><label>* Email</label> <input type="text" id="email" /></li>
              <li><label>* First Name</label> <input type="text" id="fname" /></li>
              <li><label>* Last Name</label> <input type="text" id="lname" /></li>
              ....
          </ul>
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am suspecting that this is caused by the iframe, but it works just fine in other browsers.
Also I could not change the page design(using iframe) right away for practical reasons.

[safari autofill http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/4085/autofill.gif](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/4085/autofill.gif)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IS that a system generated autofill or one youve created with css/html/js? Also how how is the element to which it belongs positioned on the page? Can you post your from markup and css?

Comment: this the system generated autofill